# Backup mysql table data selectivly from remote server into SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql

What I need to do, is to make a sql backup file ("Generate Insert Statements") of certain table data. I want to do this monthly.

Sample select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= "01-01-2012" AND date < "01-02-2012"
```

The case is I need to backup from remote sql server. Seems, I can't use `mysqldump` then (?)

So, shall I just write a PHP script to generate those statements? 
It seems a little barbaric solution ;)

Sorry, this matter seems pretty basic, but I'm quite confused with it already.

btw. tables are partially InnoDB and partially MyISAM

Comment: Just because the server is remote does not in itself preclude the use of `mysqldump` - it depends on whether the server permits incoming connections from your host.

Comment: Thanks for rapid response.

Yes, I can connect from my host, if that's what you mean. Sorry, but I can't figure out how to actually use mysqldump remotly, saving backup files on local machine.

Comment: you can use `mysqldump -h hostname....` to connect remotely, you can either use hostname or IP

Answer (score 0):

You ask a range of questions...

If the remote machine is unix, write a little bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/mysqldump -h db_server -u user_name -ppassword --WHERE 'date >= "01-01-2012" AND date < "01-02-2012"' database_name table_name | gzip > output.sql.gz
```

Things to note:

1. The password is hardcoded in the script.  Use a less-privileged user account.
2. Your date range is also hardcoded, but that's easy enough to make generic.
3. There's no space between '-p' and the password.

For innodb, use --single-transaction.  For myisam, I guess you're stick with --lock-tables.

Then run this script in a cron job.

If you have trouble connecting, check your firewall and mysql user permissions.

And my $0.02...  writing php scripts that run shell commands is really lazy.  Write shell scripts for those.  You'll sleep better.

Good luck.